# DOM not updating automatically despite functioning countdown TS, JS

Tags: javascript, typescript, dom

**Question:**
I am working on a countdown timer using JavaScript, and the functionality seems to be working fine. However, I am facing an issue where the DOM is not updating automatically. I've tried using `setInterval` in various ways and places, but the issue persists.
I'm relatively new to JavaScript and TypeScript, be patient please, (I solve this problem with without using classes, I want make this class to for reference to other projects)

**Code Overview:**
I have a `CountdownDate` class with methods to calculate remaining days, hours, minutes, and seconds. The countdown itself is initiated on a specific date, and the goal is to update the DOM dynamically.

**Problem:**
The countdown itself is accurate, and the console logs show the correct values. Still, the displayed values on the DOM are not updating in real-time.

**Attempts to Solve:**
I have attempted to use `setInterval` to update the remaining time at one-second intervals. Additionally, I've used `setTimeout` within the `app` method to check if the countdown has ended. Despite these efforts, the DOM doesn't seem to reflect the updated values.

**Code Snippet:**

```js
type Months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
type Weekdays = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];

const months: Months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
const weekdays: Weekdays =  ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];



const sold = document.querySelector<HTMLHeadingElement>('.sold');
const deadline = document.querySelector<HTMLDivElement>('.deadline');
const items = document.querySelectorAll<HTMLHeadingElement>('.deadline-format .times');

class CountdownDate {
  constructor(
    public year: number = 0,
    public month: number = 1,
    public day: number = 1,
    public hours: number = 0,
    public minutes: number = 0,
    public seconds: number = 0,
    public startedDate: Date = new Date(),
    public targetDate: Date = new Date(year, month - 1, day, hours, minutes, seconds),
    public startedTime: number = startedDate.getTime(),
    public RemainingTime: number = targetDate.getTime() - startedDate.getTime(),
  ) { }

  private static staticTime(t?: 'year' | 'month' | 'hour' | 'min'): number {
    if (t === 'hour') {
      return 60 * 60 * 1000;
    } else if (t === 'min') {
      return 60 * 1000;
    }
    return 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // Default to days
  }

  get RemainingDays(): number {
    let oneDay = CountdownDate.staticTime();
    return Math.floor(this.RemainingTime / oneDay);
  }

  get RemainingHours(): number {
    let oneDay = CountdownDate.staticTime();
    let oneHour = CountdownDate.staticTime('hour');
    return Math.floor((this.RemainingTime % oneDay) / oneHour);
  }


  get RemainingMinutes(): number {
    let oneMinute = CountdownDate.staticTime('min');
    let oneHour = CountdownDate.staticTime('hour');
    return Math.floor((this.RemainingTime % oneHour) / oneMinute);
  }

  get RemainingSeconds(): number {
    let oneMinute = CountdownDate.staticTime('min');
    return Math.floor((this.RemainingTime % oneMinute) / 1000);
  }


  public countedTime() {
    let arrTimes = [
      countdownDate.RemainingDays,
      countdownDate.RemainingHours,
      countdownDate.RemainingMinutes,
      countdownDate.RemainingSeconds,
    ];
    return arrTimes
  }

  get check() {
    return this.RemainingTime < 0;
  }

  app(callback: any) {
    if (this.check) {
      clearInterval(callback);
      deadline!.innerHTML = '<b>Sorry, the time has expired!</b>';
    } else {
      setInterval(callback, 1000);
      return this.countedTime;
    }
  }
}


let countdownDate = new CountdownDate(2024, 3, 1);

const year = countdownDate.targetDate.getFullYear();
const hours = countdownDate.targetDate.getHours();
const minutes = countdownDate.targetDate.getMinutes();
const month = months[countdownDate.targetDate.getMonth()];
const date = countdownDate.targetDate.getDay();
const dayWeek = weekdays[date];



if (sold) {
  sold.textContent = `
      sold Ends On ${dayWeek}, ${date} ${month} ${year} ${hours}:${minutes}am
      `;
} else {
  throw new Error("'sold' is undefined");
}



function updateDom() {
  let values = countdownDate.countedTime();
  items.forEach((item, i) => {
    item.textContent = String(values[i]);
  });
}
countdownDate.app(updateDom);
```

**I try** to update the `RemainingTime` by making a method and injecting it inside the `updateDom()`

```js
class CountdownDate {

  /// con

  updateRemainingTime(): void {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.RemainingTime = this.targetDate.getTime() - this.startedDate.getTime();
    }, 1000);
  }

}


function updateDom() {
  countdownDate.updateRemainingTime()
  let values = countdownDate.countedTime();
  items.forEach((item, i) => {
    item.textContent = String(values[i]);
  });
}
```

and too many others ways using `setInterval`;

**Question:**

1. How can I ensure that the DOM updates automatically as the countdown progresses?
2. Are there any specific considerations or best practices for updating the DOM in real-time with a countdown timer?

Any insights or suggestions on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Seems like you're only calling your `updateDom` method once: `setTimeout(callback, 1000);`, you probably meant for this to be `setInterval(callback, 1000);`

Comment: yes thank you, its typo mistak^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that `RemainingTime` doesn't change. In your first example, `RemainingTime` is calculated at the time your constructor triggers, and then doesn't update from there onwards. In your other exmaple, where you're attempting to update `RemainingTime` in a loop, your not taking into account that `startedDate` is a fixed value that also doesn't change. So the calculation will always yield the same number, as `startedDate` is also only set in the constructor, and so it doesn't represent the current time. I would suggest using your first example, but create a getter for `RemainingTime` so you can calculate it when it's accessed, something like this:

```js
get RemainingTime() {
  const offsetDate = Math.max(this.startedDate, new Date());
  return this.targetDate.getTime() - offsetDate;
}
```

Note this is just an example, where I take the max between the current time and the started date. If the started date is in the future, the countdown won't countdown, but you can modify this behaviour and calculation to your expected behaviour.

```js
const months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
const weekdays = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];

const sold = document.querySelector('.sold');
const deadline = document.querySelector('.deadline');
const items = document.querySelectorAll('.deadline-format .times');

class CountdownDate {
  constructor(
    year = 0,
    month = 1,
    day = 1,
    hours = 0,
    minutes = 0,
    seconds = 0,
    startedDate = new Date(),
    targetDate = new Date(year, month - 1, day, hours, minutes, seconds),
    startedTime = startedDate.getTime()
  ) { 
    this.year = year;
    this.month = month;
    this.day = day;
    this.hours = hours;
    this.minutes = minutes;
    this.seconds = seconds;
    this.startedDate = startedDate;
    this.targetDate = targetDate;
    this.startedTime = startedTime;
  }

  static staticTime(t) {
    if (t === 'hour') {
      return 60 * 60 * 1000;
    } else if (t === 'min') {
      return 60 * 1000;
    }
    return 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // Default to days
  }

  get RemainingDays() {
    let oneDay = CountdownDate.staticTime();
    return Math.floor(this.RemainingTime / oneDay);
  }

  get RemainingHours() {
    let oneDay = CountdownDate.staticTime();
    let oneHour = CountdownDate.staticTime('hour');
    return Math.floor((this.RemainingTime % oneDay) / oneHour);
  }


  get RemainingMinutes() {
    let oneMinute = CountdownDate.staticTime('min');
    let oneHour = CountdownDate.staticTime('hour');
    return Math.floor((this.RemainingTime % oneHour) / oneMinute);
  }

  get RemainingSeconds() {
    let oneMinute = CountdownDate.staticTime('min');
    return Math.floor((this.RemainingTime % oneMinute) / 1000);
  }


  countedTime() {
    let arrTimes = [
      countdownDate.RemainingDays,
      countdownDate.RemainingHours,
      countdownDate.RemainingMinutes,
      countdownDate.RemainingSeconds,
    ];
    return arrTimes
  }

  get check() {
    return this.RemainingTime < 0;
  }

  app(callback) {
    if (this.check) {
      clearInterval(callback);
      deadline.innerHTML = '<b>Sorry, the time has expired!</b>';
    } else {
      setInterval(callback, 1000);
      return this.countedTime;
    }
  }
  
  get RemainingTime() {
    const offsetDate = Math.max(this.startedDate, new Date());
    return this.targetDate.getTime() - offsetDate;
  }
}


let countdownDate = new CountdownDate(2024, 3, 1);

const year = countdownDate.targetDate.getFullYear();
const hours = countdownDate.targetDate.getHours();
const minutes = countdownDate.targetDate.getMinutes();
const month = months[countdownDate.targetDate.getMonth()];
const date = countdownDate.targetDate.getDay();
const dayWeek = weekdays[date];


if (sold) {
  sold.textContent = `
      sold Ends On ${dayWeek}, ${date} ${month} ${year} ${hours}:${minutes}am
      `;
} else {
  throw new Error("'sold' is undefined");
}



function updateDom() {
  let values = countdownDate.countedTime();
  items.forEach((item, i) => {
    item.textContent = String(values[i]);
  });
}
countdownDate.app(updateDom);
```

```html
<h1 class="sold"></h1>
<div class="deadline"></div>
<div class="deadline-format">
  Days: <h4 class="times"></h4>
  Hours: <h4 class="times"></h4>
  Minutes: <h4 class="times"></h4>
  Seconds: <h4 class="times"></h4>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your insightful response! I truly appreciate your expertise and guidance. Your observation about the RemainingTime not updating correctly was spot on. I've implemented your suggestion by creating a getter for RemainingTime, taking into account the current time with the offsetDate. and i work in the suggested problem when we set a started date Here's the updated code:

Comment: ```typescript
get RemainingTime(): number {
    if (this.startedDate.getTime() === new Date().getTime()) {
    const offsetDate = Math.max(this.startedDate as unknown as number, new Date() as unknown as number);
    return this.targetDate.getTime() - offsetDate;
    }
    const offsetDate = Math.min(this.startedDate as unknown as number, new Date() as unknown as number);
    return this.targetDate.getTime() - offsetDate;
  }
```